# is every antiderivarive an integral?

Tags: real-analysis

Given a function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, can every antiderivative $F$ of $f$ be expressed as $$F(x)=f(x_0)+\int_{x}^{x_0}f(t)\mathrm dt$$ for some $x_0$?

Comment: No, take $f=0$ your formula gives $F=0$ and not $F(x)=C$ where C is any constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Riemann integration:
No. There are functions which can have an anti-derivative without being (Riemann) integrable.

In other words, a function may be differentiable without the derivative being integrable. One such example is [Volterra's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra%27s_function).

Another example could be $F : [-1, 1] \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$F(x) := \begin{cases} x^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x = 0 \end{cases}$$

In this case, you can verify that $F$ is differentiable but $F'$ is not bounded. (The earlier example is nicer in that the derivative is bounded and still not integrable.)